# Poisson process question, exponential times

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Two teams A and B play a game. Teams score according to a Poisson process of
rates λA and λB, respectively. Whoever reaches M points first wins the match (but both
teams go to the end of M points).

a) What is the probability of team A wins given that team B has reached M points after a (non-random) time?

b) What is the probability of team A wins the match?

I think that in question b, the sum of the exponential times until the M point  has:

SA ~ Gamma(M, λA) and SB ~ Gamma(M, λB) distribution for team A and B respectively.

The probability that team A wins the match is P(SA < SB). Is this correct?

Any hints for the question a)? I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: The Poisson process is just the continuous version of tossing a coin repeatedly. The probability of heads for the coin you're tossing maps to the rate, $\lambda$ of the Poisson process. I suspect both questions can be simplified to a game between two gamblers tossing coins where the probability of heads are proportional to the two rates.

Answer (score 1):

Part a says that assume Team B has reached M points at a non random time $t$. What’s the probability that A wins. I want the prob. that A reached M points before time *t*, which is

$$\sum_{I=M+1}^\infty \frac {e^{-\lambda_At}(\lambda_A t)^I}{I!}$$